# ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames(); doesn't return results if traversal object not set in gremlin-javascript

Tags: janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have a react/node.js app that connects to a JanusGraph remote server via the gremlin-javascript client.  All works fine if I establish a remote connection and supply an existing graph name to establish the traversal object.

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const client = new gremlin.driver.Client('ws://'+req.body.graphURL+'/gremlin', {traversalSource:  req.body.graphName+'_traversal'});
let gremlin_query = 'ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames();';
const result = await client.submit(gremlin_query);
console.log('GetGraphNames raw result: ', result);
```

This all works as long as the graph name exists on the remote server.  If we don't know what graph names are present on the remote server, this call returns no results.

I have tried the following gremlin client settings to initiate an anonymous traversal object.  None of them worked.

```
const client = new gremlin.driver.Client('ws://'+req.body.graphURL+'/gremlin', {traversalSource: 'g'});
const client = new gremlin.driver.Client('ws://'+req.body.graphURL+'/gremlin', {traversalSource: 'ConfigurationManagementGraph_traversal'});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you were very close to the solution. Just drop "_traversal" from "ConfigurationManagementGraph_traversal"

```
const client = new gremlin.driver.Client('ws://'+req.body.graphURL+'/gremlin', {traversalSource: 'ConfigurationManagementGraph'});
```